# How can I send my json to my view with node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, spotify

I have a previous question about this so take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561845/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-playlists-by-user-with-the-spotify-web-api).

I can now login to spotify and get the playlists of the user that is loged in. I now want to send these playlists (they are in json) to a view of to an html page or ...

This is what my code looks like:

```
app.get('/playlists', function(req, res) {
  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);
  var scope = 'playlist-read-private';
  var options = {
    url:"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists",
    headers:{
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
      'response_type': 'code',
      'client_id': client_id,
      'scope': scope,
      'state': state
    },
    json:true
  };
  request.get(options, function(error, req, body){
    console.log(body);
    //Here I want to send the json to the view
    res.send(body);
  });
});
```

The problem with this code "`res.send(body);`" is that I get this as url: localhost:8888/playlists and in this page I just see the json. I would like to send it to a view where I can chose what info I show. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @aring This is my new question

Comment: And what is a "view", are you using a view-engine, like Jade, EJS etc?

Comment: I found some info to do this with ejs but don't know how to use it

Comment: But any way to send it and use it on a page would be fine

Comment: First you'll need a page, and probably a templating engine, otherwise, how would you use the object in the page?

Comment: Thats my question how can I make this work from this scope of code. I already do this: app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');

Comment: And now you'd need a .ejs file containing HTML, and to read the EJS documentation to understand how it works, then you'd just pass the data as `res.render('myFile', {data : body})` etc.

Comment: Ok so I did this and now I get:  Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "path to file"

Comment: Then there's no file where there should be a file ?

Comment: this node code is in a file app.js at the same level I have a map views and in this map there is a file index.ejs so I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can use an ajax request to the server with a library of your choice, and when you receive the data after the ajax, you update your view using the data. With jQuery you might do something like:

```
var jqxhr = $.get('/playlist', {parameters});
jqxhr.done(function(data){
//data is your json response you can manipulate.
});
```

You might also want to use res.json() witch is more appropriate to send json responses in express.

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a JSON you can do this

```
  return res.status(200).json({ "text": "Hello World!" });
```

Comment: Yes this works but this is not a way to send it to a page where I have like HTML. And on that page I would like to show the playlists but not in json.